Google sheets importdata with dynamic elements
I am trying to list crypto in Google Sheets, I found this URL that lists the list of all crypto but I don't want to type it manually every time the URL.
the URL is the following: https://cryptoprices.cc/BTC/
so the function should be like this: =importdata("https://cryptoprices.cc/BTC/")
I tried to concatenate to join all the elements with a list of crypto but it gave me a N/A
=CONCATENATE(L1;C4;)&"/"""
L1 is the URL and the C4 is the crypto  and the / is the last character or the URL
thanks

For example if your sheet has:

In A1 write https://cryptoprices.cc/
In B1 write your crypto symbol. For example BTC
In C1 write =IMPORTDATA(CONCATENATE(A1,B1,"/"))



You may try:
=importdata(concat(L1;C4))


